# Using ng-switch to swap templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-switch

I'm trying to switch a "sign in" form for a "sign up" form whenever the user clicks on the "Sign Up" button in my angular app, but at the moment nothing is happening when the button is clicked; *The sign in form remains on the screen and there are no console errors.* Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

I'm attempting to do this purely in html, is this even possible to achieve?

EDIT: I included a signup function in my `UserCtrl` which takes care of signing in/ out. Now when I click on sign up the alert is trigger but I get a console error saying `TypeError: boolean is not a function`.

```
$scope.signup = function() {
    alert('signup function hit');
    $scope.signup = true;
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app="myApp" >
<head>
    <title> My App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/signin.css">
     <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div ng-switch on="view.name">

    <div ng-switch-default ng-controller="UserCtrl">

        <div ng-show="!isAuthenticated">
            <form class = "form-signin">

                <div class="control-group">
                    <img src="img/logo.png">
                    <br />
                    <div class="controls">
                        <br />
                        <input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder = "Email Address" >
                    </div>

                    <br />
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder = "Password" >
                </div>
                <div class="controls">
                    <button class = "btn btn-default" ng-click="signIn()">Sign In</button>
                    <button class = "btn btn-primary" ng-click="view.name = 'signup'">Register</button>


                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


    <div ng-switch-when="signup" ng-controller = "UserNewCtrl" >
        <label>
             This is where my form should be when my signup button is clicked.
        </label>
    </div>  


//This part of index.html is only shown when a user has been authenticated

    <div ng-show="isAuthenticated">

        <div class="col-md-2">
            //MenuBar code is here
        </div>
        //Other templates get loaded here
    <div class="col-md-10">

    <div ng-view></div>

</div>

</div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/transition.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-utils.js"></script>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

MainCtrl.js:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.view={
      name: ''
    }; 
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve your requirement you need a wrapper controller that hold ng-switch `on` model because  [ngSwitch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) creates `child scope`.

You can design your view like

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-switch on="view.name">
    <div ng-switch-default ng-controller="signInCtrl">
      <h1>this is sign in page</h1>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="signin()">sign in</a>
      <br>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="view.name = 'signup'">go to sign up page</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="signup" ng-controller="signUpCtrl">
      <h1>this is sign up page</h1>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="signup()">sign up</a>
      <br>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="view.name = null">go to sign in page</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here `mainCtrl` holds `view.name` and by default `ng-switch-default` works means your `sign in page`, then when you click

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="view.name = 'signup'">go to sign up page</a>
```

`view.name` model changed and your `sign-up` page appear.

Check the [**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/6HQm4EuM6gIzwLPkL6I1?p=preview)

Comment: That looks great in the demo, but when I try to replicate in my app a blank page loads when I click on sign up- can you have a look at my edit?

Comment: Never mind- I had a stray div tag. This works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

move the app controller to the html tag, then the directive in your body tag should read if you want to match an expression

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <body ng-switch="signup">
```

see [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch)

where signup is a boolean in your myApp scope, that will presumably be changed when the signIn criteria is satisfactory

```
$rootScope.signup = true;
```

you can also achieve similar with the ng-show and ng-hide directives

Comment: Would this boolean go in my signup Ctrl? Or should I have a main Ctrl for the entire app? An example of what this might look like would be greatly appreciated, very new to the whole MVC concept.

Comment: probably you should have a separate controller for signin/out but this might set a flag in the application controller, really depends on your requirements - there are many examples out there of sign in for single page apps

Comment: SignIn is a different function that is called when the user inputs their username and password information and then clicks on the sign in button. The ng-click for "signup" is the one which needs to switch the templates..

Comment: @alfonsob after setting `ng-switch="signup"` on body and trying to set this value like `$scope.signup = true;` how this works ?

Comment: @Reza i was assuming that signup was being set in the app controller which should be on the html tag, have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Reza also your answer is more complete so have upvoted it as the more correct answer